# Brave New Number Theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, homotopy-theory

I suppose this is an extremely general question, so I apologize, and perhaps it should be deleted.  On the other hand it's an awesome question.

Is it clear exactly how much (assumedly algebraic) number theory can written down diagrammatically, and if so, has there been any effort to write such problems in the category of spectra (whichever category you like) and solve problems there?  It seems that some problems may become easier to solve, if only because there are in some sense "more" spectra to work with than there are regular algebraic objects (i.e. we have the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum for whatever ring or field of whatever, but we also have things that don't come from any algebraic object).

I have heard about Rognes' work on Galois extensions in this sense, and that there are lots of connections to things like Morava K-theory (and the associated spectra), and plan on at least attempting to pursue such ideas.

Comment: Can I get a comment explaining the down vote?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to think of how to say this diplomatically.  I downvoted the question because it is way too broad and speculative.  It has the flavor of "Here are two big fields of mathematics.  Are there any connections between them?".  Such questions are a little too b.s'y for my taste.

Comment: (though just to give you something in return, there do exist deep connections between algebraic topology and arithmetic algebraic geometry; see, for instance, the work of Voevodsky on Milnor's conjecture and the Bloch-Kato conjecture),

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm not really intending to ask "Are there any connections here?" though I've been known to ask such questions. To put a label on it to avoid it just being a "discussion question" I would say it's primarily a reference request.  I.e., who (if anyone) is doing this? Obviously Galois theory can be framed thusly, is that the end of the story? Maybe that's still too broad, but it is genuinely a question I'd like some answers to.

Comment: And ultimately, my main question is, is there a well defined piece of number theory that we can, with a suitable dictionary, write down verbatim inside of homotopy theory using this "Brave New Algebra" idea?

Comment: One last thing... I'm not asking if there are connections between number theory and homotopy theory. That would indeed be a sort of ridiculous question, and I know the answer. There is lots of interbreeding going on.  I'm really talking about this above "translation".

Comment: this IS an awesome question.

Comment: Always fun to see people from one's own department mentioned. Rognes was my topology lecturer some years ago. Here are some talks he has given http://folk.uio.no/rognes/lectures.html, perhaps some of them can be of interest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for but, since there has been no other answers, it may be of some use. Recently, I have enjoyed finding out how wonderful and mysterious the relationship between (algebraic) number theory and low-dimensional topology is through the links between Galois groups and homotopy/fundamental groups. In particular the framing of properties of prime numbers in class field theory and arithmetic geometry having duality correlations with knots, links and three-dimensional manifolds! This subject of **Arithmetic Topology** was [hinted time ago by several people](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/index.php/who-dreamed-up-the-primesknots-analogy.html), like D. Mumford and B. Mazur, which has very recently got its first MARVELOUS book:

- **Morishita, M.** - *[Knots and Primes: An Introduction to Arithmetic Topology](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-1-4471-2157-2)*, Springer 2011.

Some of the first explorations on this were:

- **Mazur, B.** - *[Remarks on the Alexander Polynomial](http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Emazur/papers/alexander_polynomial.pdf)*,
- **Mazur, B.** - *[Notes on Étale Cohomology of Number Fields](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1973_4_6_4/ASENS_1973_4_6_4_521_0/ASENS_1973_4_6_4_521_0.pdf)*,
- **Morishita, M.** - *[Analogies between Knots and Primes, 3-Manifolds and Number Rings](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3399v1)*,
- **Kohno T.; Morishita M.** (eds.) - *[Primes and Knots](http://books.google.es/books?id=htTjE4NmWUcC&lpg=PA237&dq=0821834568&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, AMS 2006.

The whole point is the study of the fundamental groups of topology but from a number-theoretic perspective, that is, working with the (étale) algebraic fundamental group of varieties and schemes as originally thought by A. Grothendieck in his **[anabelian geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabelian_geometry)**. For this and as a prerequisite to Morishita's book, along with standard arithmetic geometry, one should get the specific background on the relationship of Galois gropus and fundamental groups of schemes, provided by:

- **Szamuely, T.** - *[Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521888506)*, CUP 2009.
- **Schneps, L.** (ed.) - *[Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521808316)*, CUP 2011.

These new dualities between apparently so different worlds may open the door to a deep understanding of the mysterious arithmetic-topologic relationship.