# Curse of Dimensionality: hypercube inside a hypersphere

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits

Exercise 2.5 of Izenman's *Modern Multivariate Statistical Techniques*:

> Consider a hypercube of dimension $r$ and sides of length $2A$ and
>   inscribe in it an $r$-dimensional sphere of radius $A$. Find the
>   proportion of the volume of the hypercube that is inside the
>   hypersphere, and show that the proportion tends to $0$ as the
>   dimensionality $r$ increases. In other words, show that all the
>   density sits in the corners of the hypercube.

Let $C$ be the volume of the hypercube, and $S$ be the volume of the hypersphere.
Then
$$\dfrac{C}{S} = \dfrac{(2A)^r}{2\pi^{r/2}A^r/[r\Gamma(r/2)]} = \dfrac{2^{r-1}r\Gamma(r/2)}{\pi^{r/2}}\text{.}$$
Does this really tend to $0$? If so, I don't see it and I don't think this would be true... since (I would think it's obvious that) $r\Gamma(r/2) > \pi^{r/2}$ for large $r$... or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem, but you might try [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) if you haven't already.

Comment: You are computing the ratio $C/S$ of the volume of the **whole** hypercube to that of the whole hypersphere. This is not what the question asks... it asks for the ratio $C^\prime/C$, where $C^\prime$ is the volume of the intersection of the hypercube and the hypersphere.

Comment: @ClementC. I suppose I'm misinterpreting "inscribed" (since I haven't taken geometry in years and took it to mean that the hypercube is contained in the hypersphere). What does it mean here?

Comment: I'd be confused too: the word "inscribed" seems misused here, as the cube is not entirely contained in the sphere (the point is that most of it is actually outside). But the rest of the question goes in that direction.

Comment: @ClementC. Okay, so my basic impression of this is that you're basically poking the cube into the sphere... but I'm at a loss on how to compute $C^{\prime}$.

Comment: I really think there's a typo in the question. "inscribe it in" should be "inscribe in it". You're poking the sphere into the cube.The sphere is inside the cube. The part of the cube that's not in the sphere has most of the volume.

Comment: @EthanBolker Oh wow. -_- Yes, you're correct.

Comment: @EthanBolker So, is the sphere COMPLETELY inside the cube?

Comment: Yes. (Now more characters to make a legal  comment.)

Comment: Now that you have the geometry right you should see that you want the ratio $S/C$.small when $r$ is large. When $r=2$ it's $\pi/4$, when $r=3$ it's $\pi/6$,

Comment: Thank you @EthanBolker!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is which part of the hypercube volume $C$ is also inside the hypersphere, i.e. in $S\cap C$. Since the hypersphere is fully contained in the hypercube, $S\cap C=S$. So according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Closed_forms) you want

$$\frac{V(S)}{V(C)}
=\frac{A^r\frac{\pi^{r/2}}{\Gamma(\frac r2+1)}}{(2A)^r}
=\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\right)^r\cdot\frac1{\Gamma(\frac r2+1)}
$$

Now $\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\approx0.886<1$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\Gamma(x)\to+\infty$ so yes, this does tend to zero.

Since $\Gamma\left(\frac r2+1\right)=\frac r2\Gamma\left(\frac r2\right)$ the formula for $V(S)$ agrees with what you used, except that for $r=0$ you'd have $\Gamma(0)$ undefined. But for $r\to\infty$ that's irrelevant.

This whole question reminds me of [this post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/258558/35416) about hypershperes and hypercubes…